# Angular2 HTTP TypeScript Json

Tags: json, typescript, angular2-http

I have one locally stored "region.json" file like this:

```
{
  "regionId":1, 
  "region":"CAN"
},
{
  "regionId":2, 
  "region":"CEN"
}
```

I have "enviroment-app.component.ts" file which like this :

```
import {Component, View, CORE_DIRECTIVES, FORM_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/core";
import {HTTPTestService} from "./http-test.service";

@Component({
   selector: 'my-app'
})

@View({
  template: `

<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Region Id</th>
        <th>Region</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="#item of myData">
            <td>{{item.regionId}}</td>
            <td>{{item.Region}}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>`
  })
export class AppComponent {
myData:any;
}
```

and I have "http-test.service.ts" file which look like :

```
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Headers} from "angular2/http";
import {AppComponent} from "./environment_app.component";

@Injectable()
export class HTTPTestService{
constructor (private _http: Http){}

this.myData = {region:[]};
get("./region.json") {
   return this._http.get("./region.json", { headers: headers })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe
         (
         data => {
            this.myData = data;
         });
}
}
```

In the Front-End, I am only able to print the header as
[image]

I want to fetch all the json data

What I am doing wrong??
Please, Any help appreciated,

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your path needs to be related to the app folder that your components live in `app/data/region.json`.

Comment: @MaciejCaputa I tried what you said in your comment,but still not working , still headers got printed.

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, for whatever reason I assumed that you have fetching errors (you can double check in the console).
What angular version you are running?
If it is a final version then the semantic of ngFor has changed and 
*ngFor=`let item of myData' has to be used instead.
The syntax you use was used in Angular 2.x-beta.

Comment: Yeah you are using deprecated angular. @View is also deprecated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response of the json goes in a variable named myData. This variable is is a member of the service, and not your AppComponent class. However,

*ngFor="#item of myData"

In the above *ngFor, this myData variable is a part of your AppComponent class which was never filled.

Do this:

1. Make a function, as you did in your service that returns json data after reading the file.
2. Return that data back to AppComponent.
3. Assign that to myData in AppComponent.